# Drupal 7 modules. User define input for results

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm doing a project and the client wanted to have an interface that users can search for an item with several list boxes then upon submitting, several results will show in the node.
What contributed modules that I may use for such requirement? I already tried Hierarchical Select but seems not what I need. Can someone suggest a contrib module?

Here is the example from our local page here.

[image: Sample image from Robinsons Luxuria website]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use views to fetch the results and can use panels to display them

Comment: thanks sir.. thru this I received idea how to do it.. thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

I just use Views with exposed filters and Better Exposed Filters for more dynamic results